Redirection not shown in ''set -x'' output
I have a shell script that performs pgp encryption and decryption, the encryption runs with but my decryption is failing and I do not know why.  I type out the direct line and it works but fails in the script.
elif [ "$file_action" = "D" ]; then
# Use gpg to decrypt the file
gpg --decrypt $encrypted_file > $output_file

when I type this out manually it works with no issue.   setting my script to set -x it displays the following:
gpg --decrypt C:\encrypted.txt.gpg

the script line drops off the > output file and I cant figure out why.  I have tried > and it errors and says invalid option and tried "$output_file" but it gives the dropped off result. I manually type out the line it works with no issues.
tried ">" and i tried "$output_file" 


but my decryption is failing how do you know it is failing?

Which shell are you using ? (e.g. bash/ksh/csh). Did you try to print the variables (input and output) inside script before executing the command ? I would also give complete path of gpg and not just write gpg e.g. like /bin/gpg. Many times when you run the command on the shell it will work due to env being already set.

I am using bash and it is not decrypting the file

Every question with the shell tag is a "shell script issue". Your question title should be descriptive enough that someone can tell, from the title alone, if they have the same issue and will be able to solve it with your answers.

That said, in general, gpg -o "$output_file" -d "$encrypted_file" is generally more appropriate. (Note the quotes -- if whitespace or glob characters are present in any of the names, they're important; whereas the > must not be quoted if you want it to be parsed as syntax).

you can use set -vx to see the line (or block of code (while, for loops, etc) before it is executed. The -x shows the executing line (without redirections) with all substitutions completed and a prepended value of $PS4 (usually +), (nested $(cmd subs) and (sub shells) each generate their own extra + ) .  Good luck.

AFIK, the redirection is never shown with set -x.

gpg certainly does not silently fail. Write a minimal reproducible program, perhaps consisting only of the gpg  command, and post a screenshot of its transscript. Aside from this, please tag your question properly, so that we see which shell  you are using. Also post your shell version and the operating system.


to set -x it displays the following:
the script line drops off the > output file

set -x does not display > redirections, only the command to execute.

It does not it shows anything from >   it shows this  gpg --decrypt /dir/app/dir/DEV/printout/data.txt.gpg

@PatrickPerea That's exactly what it should do. Nothing about that set -x output is wrong. set -x isn't supposed to show redirections, so just printing the command itself without showing what setup the shell does while setting up for that command (which is what >"$output_file" does -- it's not part of the command line passed to gpg but instead is telling the shell to reconfigure stdout before running gpg) is entirely correct.
